# Script to format for absolute value doesn't work

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet with a script that formats some columns for currency. But recently, I had to modify the script so that it changes the values ​for absolute values ​as well as began to add negative values ​that are interfering in the functions in which they are used. I tried the following script but there was no change in the values ​, they remain negative. What am I doing wrong?

```
function onEdit(){
    var Spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = Spreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
    var Range = sheet.getRange('audit!f:q');
    Range.clearFormat();
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
    var cell = sheet.getRange('audit!f:q');
    cell.setNumberFormat(Math.abs('audit!f:q'));
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

The function [`setNumberFormat()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnumberformatnumberformat) needs a string with the format you want your values to be displayed in. For example if you put `'0.000'` as the format, the values in your cells will look like `1 -> 1.000`, `34 -> 34.000`, and so on.
You would use the function `clearFormat()` to remove this formatting.

`Math.abs()` will be used to modify the actual value of a variable and therefore it is not a format.

So in this case you would need to loop with the values in the range and use the `Math.abs()` function on each one of them in order to get what you need.

I modified your code so it can take the values in the range and do what I described above. I also removed the repeated code.

```js
function onEdit(){
    var Spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = Spreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
    var Range = sheet.getRange('Sheet1!a:b');    
    var cell = Range.getValues();
    Range.clearFormat();
    for(var row in cell)
    {
      for(var col in cell[row])
      {
         cell[row][col] = Math.abs(cell[row][col]);
      }
    }    
    Range.setValues(cell);    
 }
```

Let me know if this doesn't work for you.